# Statement of the Perron-Frobenius Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

Basically, I'm having trouble proving the last part of statement 4 below. The problem comes down to showing that if $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is an irreducible non-negative matrix, $x>0$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated with the eigenvalue $\rho_A$ and there is a number $\mu$ such that $Ax\leq \mu x$, then $\rho_A=\mu$.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By applying the first part of theorem 1 to $A^T$, we see that $A$ has a positive left eigenvector $v$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_\max$. It follows that $\lambda_\max v^Ty=v^TAy\le \mu v^Ty$. Since $y$ is nonzero and nonnegative, $v^Ty$ is positive. Therefore $\lambda_\max\le\mu$.

When $\mu=\lambda_\max$, we have $\lambda_\max v^Ty=v^TAy\le \mu v^Ty=\lambda_\max v^Ty$. Therefore $v^T(\mu y-Ay)=0$. As $v>0$ and $\mu y-Ay\ge0$, we must have $\mu y-Ay=0$. Thus $y$ is also an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\mu=\lambda_\max$.

In that case, if $y$ is not a scalar multiple of $x$, then for some appropriate $t>0$, the vector $z=x-ty$ is nonnegative and it has both positive and zero entries. Let $\mathcal I\sqcup\mathcal J$ be a partition of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ such that $z(\mathcal I)>0$ and $z(\mathcal J)=0$. From $Az=\lambda_\max z$, we obtain $A(\mathcal J,\mathcal I)z(\mathcal I)=0$ and in turn $A(\mathcal J,\mathcal I)=0$. This contradicts the assumption that $A$ is irreducible. Hence $y$ must be a scalar multiple of $x$.

Comment: Hi, the conclusion that $y$ must be a scalar multiple of $x$ follows from your second paragraph and the third statement of the theorem. I am stuck with the converse direction. Suppose that $y=tx$ with $t>0$.So, we get that $t\lambda_{\max} x=t Ax\leq t\mu x$, and therefore, $\lambda_{\max} x=Ax\leq \mu x$. How conclude that $\lambda_{\max}=\mu$ from the previously inequality?

Comment: @EdsonSantos The converse is false. E.g. in the scalar case where $A=1$, if we take $y=1$ and $\mu=2$, we have $Ay\le\mu y$, but $\lambda_\max=1\ne2=\mu$. In fact, if $y$ is a (nonnegative) scalar multiple of $x$, we have $Ay\le\mu y$ for every $\mu\ge\lambda_\max$.